# I want to add a column, what is wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

What is wrong with this query?

```
ALTER TABLE KARGO ADD COLUMN test VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DEFAULT t` bit is wrong.

You need to quote the default value `DEFAULT 't'`

Answer (score 0):

The default value should be quoted as the field is varchar ,
Correct syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE KARGO ADD COLUMN testt VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't'
```

Comment: Or a float, or a hex, or a binary or a boolean or a null or a... heck most things are unquoted *except* strings.